# How to reference a set of model fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Let's say I had the following Django model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

My app can search for people based on some criteria and then return a table with the results, showing only specific columns that the user requested.

Now I want to store searches in the database, along with the columns that are displayed.

```
class SavedSearch(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    q_object = models.BinaryField()
    display_fields = ???
```

What is the best way to store which fields from the Person model will be displayed?

Currently I'm just storing a JSON list of the field names (e.g. `['name','age']`) in a TextField but I'm wondering if there's a better way to store references to model fields.

I'd also like to be able to store fields from related (through ForeignKey) models. So something like `['name','age','company__website']`.

Comment: How are you returning the results?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you can not save the reference to model fields that way, but you can use a computed property that will save the model name and return field references as required -

- Save the model name along with the fields.

  ```
  class SavedSearch(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField()
      q_object = models.BinaryField()
      model_name = models.CharField() # 'app_label.Person'
      display_fields = models.CharField() # 'name,age,company__website' -> comma separated vaulues
  ```
- Then add the computed property -

  ```
      @property
      def display_fields_property(self):    
          from django.apps import apps
          properties = [] 
          # get the model class using apps from django.apps
          model = apps.get_model(app_label=self.model_name.split('.')[0], model_name=self.model_name.split('.')[1]) 
          for x in self.display_fields.split(','):
              # get the property from the model class
              properties.append(getattr(model, x)
          # properties contains field reference of the model fields
          return properties
  ```